# Strange display behavior with IE8 on localhost vs dev server

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

Just started a site, using standard html/css - nothing fancy. Just divs to create a framed look.  The server code is asp.net (4.0).

When I debug the program locally out of visual studio 2012, the page looks exactly as I designed it in all of my browsers (ie8/ff/chrome).  When I publish it to my dev server and open it in IE8, the layout is messed up (i.e, my login box is now at bottom of page instead of center).  However, if I open that same page on the dev server with firefox or chrome, it looks correct.

I've tried deleting all the files and republishing.  I've viewed the source behind both the working (localhost) and broken (dev server) and it is identical.

Any ideas or additional troubleshooting steps I can try?

Thanks.

Edit:
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1xsQ.png (side by side of dev vs localhost)

Masterpage: http://pastebin.com/c94Pinih

Css: http://pastebin.com/Txtac3kw

Login page: (the page that is messed up in IE8): http://pastebin.com/BN5bBamP

Comment: screenshots? jsfiddle? code? or should we just guess at your markup?

Comment: I've uploaded screenshot and provided source.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- make sure all of your resources are being loaded correctly (IE8 can do this, but other tools are available)
- validating HTML/CSS
- checking your render modes locally vs in production.  If this is the issue, you can probably use the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to force a specific version of the IE render engine.
- checking for any page/script errors
- checking that the source in production matches the source when viewed locally
- checking differences between IIS

Also by "standard html/css", I assume this is HTML4/CSS2?  Do you have a link to check out?

Comment: Yes html4/css2.  The site is internal so I cannot link to it.  I edited my original post to provide pastebin and screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the updated content.  I'll need to test tomorrow where I have IE8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the top level div and it worked.  Still not sure why it worked in ie8 on the local box, but not the dev box.